# Converting JSONarray to ArrayList with Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist

Hi i have simply problem, but i can find solution. If somebody can show to me solution.

...

```
(Unirest) HttpResponse<String> paluuREST = AbaXapi.HttpResponse(aString);

enter bring outside to me long Json Array:
```

So i put this inside Arraylist and short diffrent values...

```
"{\"body\":[{\"id\":\"1bc4aa42-1ef9-11e7-b023-97a5ff9c3a97\",\"name\":\"DFB-572\",\"imei\":13226005525791,\"vehicle_params\":{\"vin\":null,\"make\":null,\"model\":null,\"plate_number\":null}}]}"
```

Here is java code:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(paluuREST);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("body");


    ArrayList<Object> listdata = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

        //Adding each element of JSON array into ArrayList
        listdata.add(jsonArray.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("Each element of ArrayList");
    for(int i=0; i<listdata.size(); i++) {
        //Printing each element of ArrayList
        System.out.println(listdata.get(i));
    }
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["body"] is not a JSONArray.
at org.json.JSONObject.wrongValueFormatException(JSONObject.java:2628)
```

So how can be?  How i need to change code, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more carefull in the formulation of the question, if everything is brought to the right, then there are no problems.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "{\"body\":[{\"id\":\"1bc4aa42-1ef9-11e7-b023-97a5ff9c3a97\",\"name\":\"DFB-572\",\"imei\":13226005525791,\"vehicle_params\":{\"vin\":null,\"make\":null,\"model\":null,\"plate_number\":null}}]}";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONArray body = obj.getJSONArray("body");
    System.out.println(body);
    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object o : body) {
        objects.add(o);
    }
    System.out.println("objects = " + objects);
 }
```

used `org.json` lib